# Flash fla files corrupted by CVS

Tags: cvs, fla

I have saved my Flash fla files with Eclipse CVS and some where on the way, I set their ASCII\BINARY value to ASCII and now my files are totally corrupted.

Does anyone know of a way to fix fla files or any files that are binary but were saved as ASCII in CVS?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I had no success in recovering the files. The commit as ASCII instead of BINARY corrupted them from top to bottom. Lucky for me I had some recently new backups which saved the day.

My tip is not to regard CVS as a potential backup of your work. Always backup your files on an additional drive, even if they are in CVS.

Answer (score 0):

You may luck out and get things working by just setting the file type to binary. That should be sufficient to get all the mangling of `$Id$` etc. undone, and *if* that was the only problem, your files may work. Or not – corrupted files are a problem no matter how you broke them.